# How to read columns (Tab) in txt files and create lists? Python

Tags: python, txt

I'm starting to get familarized with Python and I wanted to learn how to read a txt files, like the ones that are obtained from other software, like LabView, which normally have the following structure.

*Headline*

*Other information*

*Temperature 1*  [Tab] *Temperature 2* [Tab] *Pressure*

In other words, skip the first few lines, and get the data which is separated with Tab in columns and store it in a list.

Comment: What exactly is the problem when you open the file and read the lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work for you. It reads the file and automatically detects tabs as delimiter, because it is set on whitespace per default. Other possibilities to set as delimiter are for example ';' or ',' etc.

Check: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

```
import numpy as np
np.loadtxt('data.txt',skiprows = 2)
```

Comment: Oh, nice, didn't know that function. I've observed that the values stored are float and doesn't seem to be possible to convert them to integers by putting int(). Also, and thank you for your kind answer, is there a simple way to extract the values of the, for example, first column?

Comment: Good to hear that you managed to implement the function. If it was what you were looking for then please accept the answer with the tick symbol next to my answer. :)